# How to decrypt `.signed` when the encrypted value is found in the http header instead of in a cookie?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, cookies, encryption

I send an email address as [signed](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Cookies/CookieJar/signed) cookie:

```
cookies.signed[:user_email] = { value: user.email, expires: 24.hours.from_now }
```

Later the frontend sends it back to me as an HTTP header:

```
request.headers["HTTP_USER_EMAIL"]
```

**How to then decrypt from the received header to the original email address?** I tried the line below, but it produces the error:

> NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `signed' for #String:0x00000008a57a78

```
email = request.headers["HTTP_USER_EMAIL"].signed unless (request.headers["HTTP_USER_EMAIL"] == nil)
```

With `debugger` I get a value for `request.headers["HTTP_USER_EMAIL"]` of `"Im9yZ29utcGxlLmNvbSI=--37ddc725d139f86095ae839012c31a14e"`. So the encrypted value is there.

**Difference value in cookie versus header:** If the encrypted value would be found in a cookie, you could decrypt it using `cookies.signed[:http_user_email]`. My attempts of `request.headers["HTTP_USER_EMAIL"].signed` and `request.headers.signed["HTTP_USER_EMAIL"]` are basically the same as when with a cookie you would take the encrypted value of the cookie and add .signed at the end: `"Im9yZ29utcGxlL".signed`. And that wouldn't work either. But how then to do it if the encrypted value is found in a string?

*Or would you argue there's no need to use an encrypted version of the user's email address for API authentication?* Authentication is done based on the combination of the email address and a token (the token needs to match the digest which is an encrypted version of the token).

Comment: for me `example@example.com` is already an original email address. Sidenote, instead on writing `request.headers["HTTP_USER_EMAIL"] == nil` you can use `nil?` method: `request.headers["HTTP_USER_EMAIL"].nil?`

Comment: Thanks, there was indeed a problem in the value I gave it in my test. I shall update my OP with the error message.

Comment: try `Rack::Session::Cookie::Base64::Marshal.new.decode(request.headers["HTTP_API_USER_EMAIL"])`

Comment: Thanks, it unfortunately returns `nil` (the cause is not that the header is nil, I checked). For cookies, I just use `cookies.signed[:email]`, which would decrypt the encrypted email address in the cookie. What makes it different here is that the code is not in a cookie but in the http header. I tried `request.headers.signed["HTTP_USER_EMAIL"]` but that also returns `nil`.

Comment: I unfortunately won't be able to help since am not strong in the topic :(

Comment: signed cookies don't encrypt the data - they only protect against tampering, by appending a signature. The first part of the cookie value should just be base64 encoded, although the data you have looks a little mangled.

Comment: Thanks for making this a bit clearer. Would that imply that also given that the token is already stored in an encrypted format (and each token is forced to be unique), it's not that important in this use case to use a signed cookie?

Comment: @Nick Just making sure - Are you sure you're not able to access the cookie the same way you've set, by accessing `cookies.signed[:user_email]`? Unless there's some cross domain functionality the cookie is sent with each request the front end issues, and should be available for you.

Comment: Yes, the frontend sends the cookie's value back in header. How in backend to convert that signed value back to the original email address I don't know. Tried all sorts of versions in an integration test (wouldn't know hot to get the signed value in Chrome's Postman), such as `cookies.signed(request.headers["HTTP_USER_EMAIL"])`, `request.headers.signed["HTTP_USER_EMAIL"]` and `request.headers["HTTP_USER_EMAIL"].signed`. These return respectively: `undefined method 'signed' for Rack::Test`, `undefined method 'signed' for ActionDispatch::Http::Headers` and `undefined method 'signed' for String`.

Comment: You can try using https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb#L63 (by initialising with your app's secret key perhaps) since the cookies are signed with that.

Comment: did you try mail_signed = request.headers["HTTP_USER_EMAIL"]
cookies[:mail]=mail_signed
mail = cookies.signed[:mail] ?

Comment: Setting value as a cookie and access it with signed it's a little bit clumsy. Use ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor to decrypt. Look at my answer for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At `config/initializers/secret_token.rb` you should have the password:

```
Demo::Application.config.secret_key_base = 'b14e9b5b720f84fe02307ed16bc1a32ce6f089e10f7948422ccf3349d8ab586869c11958c70f46ab4cfd51f0d41043b7b249a74df7d53c7375d50f187750a0f5'
```

To decrypt:

```
content = request.headers["HTTP_USER_EMAIL"]
unescaped_content = URI.unescape(content)

crypt = ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.new(Rails.configuration.secret_key_base)
data =  crypt.decrypt_and_verify(unescaped_content)
```

In 4.0 based on default configuration.
In 4.1 onwards you could have [config/secrets.yml](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#config-secrets-yml) instead of secret_token.rb

Answer (score 0):

set the value as cookie and access it with signed

so in your case

```
mail_signed = request.headers["HTTP_USER_EMAIL"]
cookies[:mail]=mail_signed
mail = cookies.signed[:mail]
```